# pfsense: Network freezes when squid service started in bridge mode

Tags: linux, networking, freebsd, routing, pfsense

We are using pfsense firewall in bridge mode. When squid service with Transparent proxy option is started the network freezes. On routing mode, squid works pretty well.

Squid setup is as below:

Keep Settings/Data: Checked
Allow Users on Interface : Checked
Proxy Interface(s):LAN
Transparent Proxy Interface(s):LAN

Comment: What you mean by freezes? HTTP requests or everything? You are not being clear. A transparent proxy needs to be associated with an IP. If I were doing the setup by hand I knew it would have to be associated with the WAN interface, but only accepting requests from the internal network. it is very easy to understand why it works without hitches when routing. Mind you that when setting up more convulated schemes like transparent HTTP or DNS services, you would better understand the subjacent basics to understand what you are doing and debugging it in case of problems.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro freezes the whole network and if I select WAN interface then bypass the squid(means does not block anything)

Comment: pings too? odd.

Comment: Yes able to ping. Is it work well on bridge mode on pfsense-x64-latest version.

Comment: This is not a trivial configuration. It is clearly not be supported directly by pfsense. It may work, probably may need some coaxing. I do remember when setting up native iOS VPNs in pfsense I had to add some extra rules, and that because I understood what I was doing, as I am a mix between a sysadmin and network admin. I advise you to do it in routing mode if you do not find a cut & clear tutorial detailing how to do it.